# My JPanels doesn't show as i want them

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, layout-manager

Im trying to make the look of my application to look something like this:

[image: How i want my application to look]

But when i try to make this i get something like this:
[image: How my application looks]

Here is the code i use to create my two JPanels and how i add the buttons and soo on..

```
//This is the panel that shows the image
appletRunningPanel = new ImagePanel();
appletRunningPanel.setSize(600, 300);
appletRunningPanel.validate();

//This is the panels that shows the 3 buttons
appletRunningPanel2 = new Panel(new GridLayout(1, 3));
appletRunningPanel2.setSize(600, 300);
appletRunningPanel2.add(test1);
appletRunningPanel2.add(test2);
appletRunningPanel2.add(test3);
appletRunningPanel2.validate();

//Then i add them to the applet with this:
add(appletRunningPanel);
add(appletRunningPanel2);
```

Here is the code for ImagePanel

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImagePanel() {
        setSize(600, 300);
        try {                
           image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/TCHLogo.png"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
             // handle exception...
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
     }

     @Override
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
         super.paintComponent(g);
         g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
     }

}
```

Comment: 1) JButtons are added to JPanel that contains Image?, 2) maybe you want to resiziable your image ? +1 for posting idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridLayout will stretch the component in each cell to fit the size of the cell, if you want to avoid this stretching then add the Buttons to another Panel and add that panel to the `GridLayout`.

Laying out a user interface in Java, in my experience, is all about mixing and matching Layout managers to achieve your overall goal. There are some simplified managers out there like [Mig Layout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

For you example I'd do something like this:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| panel1                                 |
|+--------------------------------------+|
|| panel2                               ||
|+--------------------------------------+|
+----------------------------------------+
+----------------------------------------+
| panel3                                 |
|+-----------++-----------++------------+|
|| panel4    || panel5    || panel6     ||
|+-----------++-----------++------------+|
+----------------------------------------+
```

- `panel1` has a [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)
- `panel2` is your `ImagePanel` and added to `panel1` via `panel1.add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);`
- `panel3` is your `GridLayout`.
- `panel4`, `panel5`, and `panel6` are all default (`FlowLayout`) and each of these `JPanel`s will contain one of your three buttons.

You can then add this to the Content Pane by setting it's Layout to `BorderLayout` and adding `panel1` via `getContentPane().add(panel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);` and `panel3` via `getContentPane().add(panel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`

It's not perfect, but it'll achieve a cleaner look for you. There is a lot more that you can add to make things appear nicer. One of my favorite layout managers is [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).

Comment: You don't need to create 6 different panels. Just two will do. First create the image panel, then create a button panel. This is just confusing things.

Answer (score 1):

You need to better understand Layout Managers. Have a look through [this handy guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and pick a layout manager that suits your need.

On the bottom panel, GridLayout doesn't respect the preferred size of the components (JButtons), it uses all the space available in the grid section.

You may need to use different layout managers for each panel, and another one again for your applet frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an intermediate JPanel
i.e

```
JPanel appletRunningPanel2Wrapper = new JPanel();
appletRunningPanel2Wrapper.add(appletRunningPanel2);
add(appletRunningPanel2Wrapper);
```